# Алгоритм метода count в Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Какой алгоритм использовали разработчики в методе count для строки в Python 3? Какая сложность этого алгоритма?

Comment: Нужно понимать, что разработчики каждого интерпретатора могут выбирать произвольную реализацию, которая будет соответствовать стандарту языка. Насколько я понимаю, вы говорите про CPython. Думаю, это стоит явно указать в вопросе.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для стандартной реализации интерпретатора Python, т.е. CPython, [насколько я понимаю](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h#L172), верно следующее:

Для поиска количества вхождений паттерна в строку используется [алгоритм Бойера — Мура](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0). Так как `count` возвращает количество неперекрывающихся вхождений подстроки в строку, то сложность работы алгоритма Бойера — Мура будет составлять O(n + m), где n + m — это сумма длин строки и паттерна.

---

Я не очень хорошо разбираюсь в структуре исходного кода CPython, но очень похоже, что метод `count` действительно описан в файле [count.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/count.h), приведённом [@Suvitruf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/15479/suvitruf). Функция, описанная в нём, содержит единственный вызов -- вызов функции `FASTSEARCH`, описание которой я нашёл в файле [fastsearch.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h), которая содержит вариант алгоритма Бойера — Мура.

---

Источники:

- [исходный код count.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/count.h)
- [исходный код fastsearch.h](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h)
- [описание алгоритма Бойера — Мура и его вариаций на википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%91%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9C%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: сам Boyer-Moore алгоритм с упрощениями от Horspool и Sunday описан в http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm (там же реализация на чистом Питоне (псевдо-код)). Описание говорит, что требование `O(nm)` в худшем случае.

Comment: @jfs если я правильно понял, то это в общем случае, когда ищутся все вхождения (в том числе и перекрывающиеся). В описании функции `count` этот вариант, вероятно специально, был убран. В случае же отсутствия перекрытий сложность алгоритма уменьшается.

Comment: точная цитата: *"no worse than the current algorithm in worst case (O(nm))"*, то есть фактический алгоритм может быть лучше. Хотя я не вижу улучшений для [`count` случая](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/5bc8fdeb2b403121f463d5e2e5914f2dd203f781/Objects/stringlib/fastsearch.h#L168-L210) по сравнению с [псевдо-кодом из статьи с цитатой](http://effbot.org/zone/stringlib.htm).

Answer (score 3):

Ну, сам алгоритм [вот](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1fe0fd9feb6a4472a9a1b186502eb9c0b2366326/Objects/stringlib/count.h):

```
#ifndef STRINGLIB_FASTSEARCH_H
#error must include "stringlib/fastsearch.h" before including this module
#endif

Py_LOCAL_INLINE(Py_ssize_t)
STRINGLIB(count)(const STRINGLIB_CHAR* str, Py_ssize_t str_len,
                const STRINGLIB_CHAR* sub, Py_ssize_t sub_len,
                Py_ssize_t maxcount)
{
    Py_ssize_t count;

    if (str_len < 0)
        return 0; /* start > len(str) */
    if (sub_len == 0)
        return (str_len < maxcount) ? str_len + 1 : maxcount;

    count = FASTSEARCH(str, str_len, sub, sub_len, maxcount, FAST_COUNT);

    if (count < 0)
        return 0; /* no match */

    return count;
}
```

Comment: Как можно заметить, здесь нет самого алгоритма, весь алгоритм спрятан в функции `FASTSEARCH`